Finding the smallest root
We are given an array $a$ of $n$ integers, such that the difference between each element $a[i]$ and the adjacent elements $a[i-1]$ and $a[i+1]$ is at most $1$.
Define a root of $a$ as an index $k$ in $1,\ldots,n$ such that $a[k]=0$.
If $a[1]<0$ and $a[n]>0$, then $a$ has at least one root. Moreover, it is possible to find a root using binary search, using $O(\log_2(n))$ operations.
In general, $a$ may have more than one root. MY QUESTION: What is the run-time of finding the smallest root (the smallest $k$ for which $a[k]=0$)? In particular: can it be done in time sub-linear in $n$?

No, consider the array that:

0 at a random index $a[i]$
0 at index $n-1$
1 at index $n$
-1 everywhere else

No sublinear algorithm can find the index $i$.
